# Google Sheets - COUNTIFS in ArrayFormula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, countif

| Project Completion Target Date | Estimated Completion Date |
| --- | --- |
| 12/31/2020 | 12/24/2020 |
| 12/31/2020 | 1/7/2021 |
|  | 1/19/2021 |
|  | 2/15/2021 |

I'm trying to create a CountIfs statement, or a CountIf inside an Array, which will evaluate one column in relation to another column, repeated for multiple rows. With multiple conditions: If B > A, and ignore the row is A is empty.

Formula So Far:

```
=COUNTIF({B2:B5}, ">"&{A2:A5})
```

Result is 3, but the desired result is 1. This formula is counting when B > null = True. But desired result is when A is empty/null, then B !> A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option.

```
=COUNT(FILTER(A2:B5,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A5)),B2:B5>A2:A5))/2
```

You can use [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to filter your data with multiple conditions then count the filtered data (divide by 2 based on the number of columns in your data)

Your conditions:

1. A should not be empty
2. B should be greater than A

Example:

Filter the set of data based on the conditions required.

```
=FILTER(A2:B5,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A5)),B2:B5>A2:A5)
```

**Output:**

- It will return a filtered data like this.
  Then you just need to use [COUNT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620) to count the filtered data. You just need to divide the result of the count based on the number of columns in your data.

[image]

Comment: "divide by 2 based on the number of columns in your data" That's GENIUS!! Thank You!!! Worked beautifully

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following filter formula

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7<>"",B2:B7>A2:A7))
```

[image]